# How to find a unknown values of state space model matrices

Tags: linear-transformations, laplace-transform, matlab, linear-control

I have the following state-space model
$$
A=
    \begin{bmatrix}
    k & 0 & 1 \\
    1 & -3 & 2 \\
    0 & 0 & -4 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
B=
    \begin{bmatrix}
    0 \\
    0\\
    1\\
    \end{bmatrix}
C =
    \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1 &0 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
D=
    \begin{bmatrix}
    0
    \end{bmatrix}
$$
Conditions for the state-space model is  "k" for which the system would be:

(i) unstable.

(ii) uncontrollable.

(iii) unobservable.

So, here how can I find the unknown value "k" in the matrix A. (Any possibility to find k without using rank tests?)

Comment: What is a state-space model? (Which conditions should be satisfied by $A,B,C,D$?!)

Comment: @dan_fulea sorry forgot to insert conditions, please check now. I updated the question with conditions. [State-space](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/State_space_model#:~:text=State%20space%20model%20(SSM)%20refers,be%20either%20continuous%20or%20discrete)

Comment: Please give a reference to a "state-space model", and best also the context where the question is extracted from. (So that the conditions may be translated in matrix language. I suppose, after having these conditions explicitly there is not too much to compute...) Please also mention the own tries, it is the way it works. (Each question should come with "context", e.g. references, literature, in which context appears the problems, first steps done and the point where one gets stuck, et caetera.)

Comment: For stability, you need that all eigenvalues of $A$ have negative real parts. For observability and controllability, you need to write down the observability and controllability matrices and check that they are not singular. All the operations yield some restrictions of $k$. Please write what did you try and where you are stucked.

Comment: @Arastas thanks but I am trying to find the K value without using state-space methods. Is there any way that I can find K without using only the transfer function of the system.?

Comment: Sure, no problem. You write the transfer function as $W(s) = C\left(sI-A\right)^{-1}B$. For stability, you need the denominator to have roots only with negative real parts. And for controllability/observability you need that there are no common zeros and poles of the transfer function, i.e., no zeros-poles cancellation.

Comment: @Arastas Hi, I have a follow up question: are the zeros in the numerator of $W(s)$? Also, if we have zeros-poles cancellation and then rewrite the transfer function accordingly, does this alter the system? If we would transform this into state-space form again, would the matrices $A$, $B$ and $C$ change? (Might sound like a silly question since the rewritten form should be equivalent to the original form, but sometimes information is lost this way.)

Comment: @SimpleProgrammer Yes, the zeros are in the num, and the poles are in the den. The zero-poles cancellation does not affect the input-output model (in the sense of Laplace transformations). However, we normally should not cancel unstable poles since we lose instability information. The matrices will change - they will be of a smaller order. However, being different in the state-space sense, they will define the same input-output relation.